# How to show a popup to non EU customers via ip look up service

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, ip, shopify

I'm trying to show a popup to non-EU customers that visit my store. 
the ip look up service i'm using has an api that returns a boolean in the body after checking if the visiting ip is from EU(true) or not(false).

I have viewed sessions from customers in the EU and the popup shows to them but the string value is reported as true.

```
<script>
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
         request.open('GET',  "https://api.ipdata.co/2601:8:be00:cf20:ca60:ff:fe09:35b5/is_eu?api-key=**test**");

          request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
        }
        if (this.responseText === 'false'){
                window.onload = function () {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    _ltk.Modal.load("Popup - Bark Control");    //popup 
                        }, 500);
                    }

                }

            };

      request.send();
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried the request with my own key and response is always `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8` for the feed requests as 'is_eu'

Comment: Btw IP address geo database can have mistakes as well

Comment: also instead of `window.onload` I recommend to us function like this ```function function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}``` because you can get response when DOM is already loaded.